# HTMLAgilityPack - Get element in class by class

Tags: c#, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I wish to get the value from the **H2** (highlighted) element within 'listicle-page' class shown below.  Currently the code gets all values in the **DIV** element while I need to just get the value of **H2** that is contained within the class below.

Consider the following HTML:

[image: Click here to see HTML]

Please see code below -

```
private void getFact()
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.rd.com/culture/interesting-facts/");

            var headerNames = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='listicle-page']").ToList();

            foreach(var item in headerNames)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.InnerText);
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you want header only, try `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='listicle-page']/h2").ToList();`

Comment: Great - That worked.  Want to add it as an answer and I'll mark it? Thanks for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your XPath `//div[@class='listicle-page']` matches `div` node with all of its descendants. If you need to select child `h2` node only, then explicitly specify it by adding `/h2`:

```
//div[@class='listicle-page']/h2
```